# Add an open file name to a cell in new workbook so I can use it as headers & use File 1 and File 2 to name my newly added workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am using msoFileDialogFilePicker to open two files to import data into a new workbook to compare. I would like to use the file names as headers in my new workbook PLUS use the file names to name my new workbook. For example, February Sales vs March Sales.xlsx and also as headings in my sheet tabs. File 1 in cell A1 and File Name 2 in cell O2. In advance, thank you!

Sub ImportSalesData()
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False

```
   Dim directory As String, Filename As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As 
         Integer
   Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim Wb2 As Workbook
   Dim sht As Worksheet



   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the first sales month"
    .Filters.Clear


    If .Show = True Then
      Filename = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))

    End If
   End With

    Workbooks.Open (Filename)

    Set range1 = Range("A:M")
    range1.Copy

    Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Compare Sales"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "Name of File 1  and Name of File 2", xlWorkbookNormal


    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the second sales month"
    .Filters.Clear


    If .Show = True Then
      Filename = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))

    End If
   End With


   Workbooks.Open (Filename)



Set range2 = Range("A:M")
range2.Copy
Workbooks("Name of File 1  and Name of File 2").Activate
Sheets("Compare Sales").Activate
Range("O1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Compare Sales").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is your code lacking that you need?

Comment: Also, you need to re-activate `ScreenUpdating` at some point in your code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `.Name` property.

It can be used as follows to return the name of Workbooks, Sheets, etc. You need this for the workbook, so you may use as follows.

```
MsgBox Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "")
MsgBox Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "")
```

You can implement it in your code as such:

```
Dim WBook1 as String
Dim WBook2 as String
WBook1 = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "")
WBook2 = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "")
```

You can then just reference `WBook1` & `WBook2` whenever you need to

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportSalesData()

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet, nm1 As String, nm2 As String

    'choose the workbooks
    Set Wb1 = ChooseWorkbook("Select the first sales month")
    If Wb1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set Wb2 = ChooseWorkbook("Select the second sales month")
    If Wb2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'get the names, ignoring the extension
    nm1 = Split(Wb1.Name, ".")(0)
    nm2 = Split(Wb2.Name, ".")(0)

    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add()
    Set sht = wbNew.Sheets(1)

    sht.Name = "Compare Sales"

    'probably should not use full-column ranges....
    sht.Range("A:M").Value = Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A:M").Value
    sht.Range("O:AA").Value = Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A:M").Value

    sht.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Wb1.Close False 'close source workbooks without saving
    Wb2.Close False

    wbNew.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & nm1 & " and " & nm2 & ".xlsx"

End Sub

'let the user pick a file...
' Returns Nothing if no selection
Function ChooseWorkbook(sTitle As String)
    Dim rv As Workbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = sTitle
        .Filters.Clear
        If .Show = True Then Set rv = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
    Set ChooseWorkbook = rv
End Function
```

Comment: For example `sht.Range("A1").Value = nm1`